# Optimize Code for longest common sequence

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I was trying to solve [this practice problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/D2/), it is also quoted below.

> The Chef is planning a buffet for the DirectiPlex inauguration party,
>   and everyone is invited. On their way in, each guest picks up a sheet
>   of paper containing a random number (this number may be repeated). The
>   guests then sit down on a round table with their friends.
>        The Chef now decides that he would like to play a game. He asks you to pick a random person from your table and have them read their
>   number out loud.  Then, moving clockwise around the table, each person
>   will read out their number.  The goal is to find that set of numbers
>   which forms an increasing subsequence.  All people owning these
>   numbers will be eligible for a lucky draw! One of the software
>   developers is very excited about this prospect, and wants to maximize
>   the number of people who are eligible for the lucky draw. So, he
>   decides to write a program that decides who should read their number
>   first so as to maximize the number of people that are eligible for the
>   lucky draw. Can you beat him to it?
>        Input    The first line contains t, the number of test cases (about 15). Then t test cases follow. Each test case consists of two
>   lines:
>
> The first line contains a number N, the number of guests invited to
>   the party.
>
> The second line contains N numbers a1, a2, ..., an separated by
>   spaces, which are the numbers written on the sheets of paper in
>   clockwise order.
>          Output     For each test case, print a line containing a single number which is the maximum number of guests that can be eligible for
>   participating the the lucky draw.

Here's the solution that I have come up with

```
// http://www.codechef.com/problems/D2/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class D2
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
    throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int numTestCases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for(int _t=0; _t<numTestCases; ++_t)
    {
      int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      StringTokenizer strtok = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
      int [] originalArray = new int[N*2];
      for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
      {
        //this concatenates the array with itself at the time of reading the input itself
        originalArray[i] = originalArray[N+i] = Integer.parseInt(strtok.nextToken());
      }
      //Now we calculate the length of the longest increasing sequence
      int maxWinners = new LongestIncreasingSequence(originalArray).lengthOfLongestIncreasingSequence();
      System.out.println(maxWinners);
    }
  }
}

class LongestIncreasingSequence
{
  private int [] array;
  private int [] longest;
  private int subsequence_size;
  public LongestIncreasingSequence(int [] A)
  {
    array = A;
    longest = new int[array.length / 2];
    longest[0] = array[0];
    subsequence_size = 1;
  }

  public int lengthOfLongestIncreasingSequence()
  {
    for(int i=1; i<array.length; ++i)
    {
      if(array[i] < longest[0])
      {
        longest[0] = array[i];
      }
      else if(array[i] > longest[subsequence_size - 1])
      {
        longest[subsequence_size++] = array[i];
      }
      else
      {
        //Make the replacement with binary search
        longest[getReplacementIndex(array[i])] = array[i];
      }
    }
    return subsequence_size;
  }

  //Method to find the correct index using binary search
  private int getReplacementIndex(int elem)
  {
    int left, right, mid;
    left = 0; right = subsequence_size - 1;
    while(right - left > 1)
    {
      mid = 1 + (right - left) / 2;
      if(array[mid] >= elem)
      {
        if(mid != right) right = mid;
        else --right;
      }
      else
      {
        left = mid;
      }
    }
    return right;
  }
}
```

The complexity is `O(n(log(n))` I'm finding the Longest Increasing Sequence by concatenating the array with itself.

This however doesn't pass the time requirement, can someone help me speed up this implementation.

Comment: As a hint: the solution will be (edit) O(nlogn), and will utilize dynamic programming.

Comment: @NominSim : Made the changes, any other suggestions?

Comment: @nikhil I suggested an incorrect algorithm in my answer (sequence `1,10,2,20,3,30` makes it return a wrong result of 6 instead of 4) so I deleted the answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm either misunderstanding the problem or really can't see where there's a sequence of 4 ascending numbers in your input?

Comment: @Voo `1,2,3,30`. The algorithm I suggested (and deleted) would find `1,2,3,10,20,30`, which is wrong.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ah the number of people doesn't have to be consecutive, didn't read it that way from the description. Ok, yeah that also explains why the obvious solution doesn't work and where the dynamic programming approach comes in.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do `N` rotations, but instead determine the longest (cyclic) run in one go. It is certainly doable, you just have to take care warping around at the end of the array.

Comment: Could you please explain this idea in more detail.

Comment: @nikhil dasblinkenlight's answer is more detailed about what I thought.